# No endpoint listening error on net.tcp

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

Service config

```
<service name="Services.MyService">
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000/Services/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint name="NetTcpService" 
        address="" 
        binding="netTcpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="TcpConfig"
        contract="Service.IMyService" />
    <endpoint 
        address="mex" 
        binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpConfig" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

Client code:

```
var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9000/Services/MyService/mex");
var binding = new NetTcpBinding { TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed, SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue };
var channel = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, endPoint);
var proxy = channel.CreateChannel();
```

Error:

> No Endpoint listening at "net.tcp://localhost/Services/MyService/mex"

tcp services are running, firewall is off. Not sure what's missing.

Comment: I get basically the same message if I use endpoint net.tcp://localhost:9000/Services/MyService

Comment: See my response - you probably also need to change to `TransferMode.Buffered` when creating your binding (unless that `TcpCOnfig` binding configuration - which you **haven't shown** in your post...... - would set up streamed transfer mode)

Comment: Can you show us the `<bindings>` part of your server-side config, please??

Comment: <binding name="TcpConfig" portSharingEnabled="true" transferMode="Streamed">

As mentioned below, this is self-hosted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **actual** service is listening at `net.tcp://localhost:9000/Services/MyService/` - so try to change your code to look like this:

```
var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9000/Services/MyService/");
var binding = new NetTcpBinding { TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered, SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue };
var channel = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, endPoint);
var proxy = channel.CreateChannel();
```

Besides changing the address, also use `TransferMode.Buffered` (instead of `Streamed`) which is the default - I don't see any configuration in your server-side config that would indicate that you're using the streamed transfer mode.

The address `net.tcp://localhost:9000/Services/MyService/mex` is the **metadata exchange** address - not your service. This endpoint is needed for your clients to be able to interrogate the service to learn about what kind of service method it offers, what parameters it expects and so forth - everything that's need to create the client-side proxy code. But this is **NOT** the service address where your actual service lives and responds to requests.

Comment: Added transferMode to the service config, and pointed client endpoint at net.tcp://localhost:9000/Services/MyService and still got the same message

Comment: @Suedeuno: how are you **hosting** your WCF service?? Self-hosted in an app, or hosted inside IIS ??